# Retrieving data programmatically from a Configuration Profile in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, x509certificate

I have been searching all over the apple documentation, including these forums, yet was not able to retrieve a certificate from a configuration profile that I had created and installed on my iPhone.

More specifically:
Using the iPhone Configuration Utility, I created a simple configuration profile that contains a certificate under the Credentials tab.

I am now trying to retrieve this certificate using my iPhone app but without any luck of coming across useful documentation/examples.

I know how to extract PKCS12 data - I just don't know where to find the certificate data to begin with.
Is there a path to the certificate data or to an NSDictionary of configuration profile values?

Comment: What is it you are ultimately trying to do? Ie. why do you need to import an installed certificate?

Comment: I am trying to authenticate a user in different apps using the same installed certificate. Are you implying that I am not supposed to access an installed certificate? Then what is the use of installing a certificate using the configuration utility? Confused, yet thankful for replies.

Comment: @Branchis did you get any solution to this? if yes, please suggest me how to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is not possible currently to read a profile. See https://devforums.apple.com/message/533356 (requires login).

Was looking for the same thing, to authenticate user as an enterprise employee.

Comment: A few months later... Is there still no way?

Comment: We also need to be able to access device certificates for enterprise applications. Any new information?

Comment: It seems that the application FullContacts knows if you have their CardDAV profile installed or not...How they do it? Screenshot here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_r-y6Jk56yKT3l2MWFvZHd1MlE/view?usp=sharing