# How do I programatically check ‘iPhone Device Configuration profile’ is installed or not on device

Tags: ios, ios5, enterprise-distribution, configuration-profile

Is there way to verify whether a particular device configuration profile is installed or not on iPhone through an iOS application? I have an iOS application which is distributed via ‘enterprise distribution’ mode and I have created a device configuration profile (generated using iPCU) where I have disabled some of device features i.e. screen capture.

As per current process I am sending device configuration profiles with email, and the recipient has to install it from the email they receive. Since it is a manual process some people are installing the app without installing the device configuration profile.

I would like to restrict this, so that if a user has not installed the profile, then s/he should not be able to run my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is not possible to read profile file. but this below link is  clear more your doubt

[Programatically check if there is a configuration profile installed or not on an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364922/programatically-check-if-there-is-a-configuration-profile-installed-or-not-on-an)

[Retrieving data programmatically from a Configuration Profile in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202812/retrieving-data-programmatically-from-a-configuration-profile-in-ios)

[iOS - Prevent iPhone Configuration Profile from being deleted OR check to see if it's installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424267/ios-prevent-iphone-configuration-profile-from-being-deleted-or-check-to-see-if)

[Installing a configuration profile on iPhone - programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically)

Comment: Thank you for your response, Seems have to go with MDM solution.